# How can I create PHP script that will update my website on specific date

Tags: php

I'm trying to create PHP script that will update my website on some specific   date. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you know anything about cron? If you do not know, then I advise you to learn about it from google. And if you fail to configure cron on your server / hosting, do not forget to google "cron online".
Well, and as an option, if you have some traffic and the script runs at least once a day, just compare the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP itself cannot execute itself at a specific time, that is instead handled by your server. You can configure your server to execute your scripts at any interval you like.

If you are using a linux based machine (most likely if you are using PHP), it is called a cronjob. You can access it by typing `crontab -e` on your command line and adding the line:

`* * * * * /path/to/your/script.php`

Those stars represent the interval, like so `minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week`

For example, to run it on the 20th of October at 9am, it would be `0 9 20 10 * /path/to/script`